# 502 Gateway Error on AWS - API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, gateway

I am creating a test web app and have deployed it to AWS Ubuntu server using nginx..

I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway error when it tries to reach my API..

I am new to this and have started node.js and all seems to working fine except when I want to perform an API call to mongodb to read or write information. it is working fine locally so I am at a loss....

GET http://ec2-54-72-145-112.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/rest/golf 502 (Bad Gateway)

this is nginx server config

```
 location /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx{ 
 alias /home/ubuntu/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/site/public; 
 } 

 location /api/ { 
 proxy_pass http://127.0.x.1:8180/api/; 
 }
```

..

I know I may not be giving enough info but hopefully someone has an idea..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The nginx error message `HTTP 502` indicates the nginx is working fine but cannot reach your specified proxy. So I'd suggest you to check whether the port and binding IP are correct.

You can check which ports are bound by which application using this command on your Ubuntu machine:

```
netstat -tulpen
```

You should see a line with the column "Local Address" and in your case the value `127.0.x.1:8180`. If it's not there try to figure out which port is bound by your node application and reconfigure the nginx to use that port.